# How to match value in enumeration to a keyword?

Tags: python, enumeration

I want to write a keyword-in-context script in which I first read a text file as an enumerated list and then return a given keyword and the five next words.

I saw that similar questions were asked for C# and I found solutions for the `enum` module in Python, but I hope there is a solution for just using the `enumerate()` function.

This is what I have got so far:

```
# Find keywords in context

import string

# open input txt file from local path

with open('C:\\Users\\somefile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f: # open file
    data1=f.read() # read content of file as string
    data2=data1.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower() # remove punctuation
    data3=" ".join(data2.split()) # remove additional whitespace from text
    indata=list(data3.split()) # convert string to list
    print(indata[:4])
    
searchterms=["text", "book", "history"]
 
def wordsafter(keyword, source):
    for i, val in enumerate(source):
        if val == keyword: # cannot access the enumeration value here
            return str(source[i+5]) # intend to show searchterm and subsequent five words
        else:
            continue

for s in searchterms: # iterate through searchterms
    print(s)
    wordsafter(s, indata)
    
print("done")
```

I was hoping I could simply access the value of the enumeration like I did here, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: `source[i+5]` is a *single* element from the list, the one five elements after the one currently being iterated - and will fail if there are less than five elements remaining.  You want a *slice* instead, something like `source[i:i+5]`, to return multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With credits to @jasonharper, your improved code:

```
import string


def wordsafter(keyword, source):
    for i, val in enumerate(source):
        if val == keyword:
            return ' '.join(source[i:i + 5])  # intend to show searchterm and subsequent five words

# wordsafter() for all instances
def wordsafter(keyword, source):
     instances = []
     for i, val in enumerate(source):
        if val == keyword:
            instances.append(' '.join(source[i:i + 5]))
     return instances

# open input txt file from local path
with open('README.md', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:  # open file
    data1 = f.read()  # read content of file as string
    data2 = data1.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()  # remove punctuation
    data3 = " ".join(data2.split())  # remove additional whitespace from text
    indata = list(data3.split())  # convert string to list

searchterms = ["this", "book", "history"]
for string in searchterms:  # iterate through searchterms
    result = wordsafter(string, indata)
    if result:
        print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @jasonharper and Xander, that fixed it. I must have been unlucky that there were never five elements remaining, so I didn't get any results whatsoever and was looking for mistakes in the wrong place. I will credit both of you when I share the script.

Comment: PS: I updated the script to find all instances of keywords in context in a txt file as this script only catches the first. Interestingly, individual results I call look great... but showing the whole output exceeds what my Jupyter Notebook can handle. And writing results to a file results in 58MB of data. I think there's a loop issue I need to fix. Once I am done, I will share the script in another answer.

Comment: @OnceUponATime I added a function which does this, I edited my code. Have not tested it, but I have no doubt it will work. Good luck with it!