# How to stop loop that iterates through an enumerated list?

Tags: python, loops, enumeration

I have started working with the `enumerate()` function in Python and would like to improve a keyword-in-context script that I first discussed in [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66972612/how-to-match-value-in-enumeration-to-a-keyword).

As the initial script only retrieved the first instance of each keyword plus its subsequent words, I tried to write a script that iterates through the whole file and compares all words to the keyword list.

What happens, however, is that I get a supposedly endless result list that my Jupyter Notebook cannot handle. I even tried forcing stop with `break` as soon as the enumeration `i` gets larger than the number of words in the analysed text file. Unfortunately, this didn't work either.

I assume I haven't fully grasped the logic behind the `enumerate()` function yet and would appreciate your advice.

This is my **current script**:

```
# Find keywords and "n" subsequent words in txt file
# credits to @jasonharper and @xander for previous updates
# cf. forum discussion on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66972612/how-to-match-value-in-enumeration-to-a-keyword

import string

# function to find keywords in context
def wordsafter(keyword, source):
        wordcount=len(source) # sample text has 5953 words in total
        print(wordcount)
        res_strings=[]    
        for i in range(0, wordcount):
            if i < wordcount:
                print(i) # prints correct range from 0 to 5952
                for i, val in enumerate(source):
                    if val == keyword:
                        res_str=(' '.join(source[i:i + 10]))  # show searchterm and subsequent n words
                        res_strings.append(res_str)
            if i > wordcount:
                break # how can I force function to check each word only once?
            
        return(res_strings) # returns endless (?) list of results?
    
# open input txt file from local path
with open('C:\\somefile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:  # open file
    data1 = f.read()  # read content of file as string
    data2 = data1.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()  # remove punctuation
    data3 = " ".join(data2.split())  # remove additional whitespace from text
    indata = list(data3.split())  # convert string to list

# define searchterms and call function    
searchterms = ["proclamation"] 
for keyword in searchterms:
    result = wordsafter(keyword, indata)
    if result:
        print(result[600000]) # prints a valid string although whole file only has 5953 items
        with open('C:\\Users\\anotherfile.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
            file.write(str(result)) # output file is so large it crashes when opened
```

Comment: Looks like you're re-defining i within your 2nd loop. Why wouldn't you use j, or another variable?

Comment: also the function should check the word just once if You loop over a list of words using for loop and not specifically checking the word more than once, why do You think it gets checked more than once?

Comment: It is supposed to be the same index number all the way through. But to be honest, the whole wordcount section only really came in when a single loop failed.

Comment: @Matiiss: because I get massive output. When I have 5900 words or so in the file, I can still call output 6000 later. But I cannot print the whole output because that causes the error in Jupyter notebook. The output I can print, though, looks great. That is why I am confused.

Comment: This is what result 6000 looks like: ```proclamation for apprehending john glover alexander cutting william adye and``` And I can even print output 600000: ```proclamation by the right honourable lord mayor of the city``` So it just never ends.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened, but running the original script on a different machine produced perfectly correct output, no forced interruptions needed:

```
# Find keywords and five subsequent words
# Updated script with credits to @jasonharper and @xander
# cf. forum discussion on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66972612/how-to-match-value-in-enumeration-to-a-keyword

import string

# function to find keywords in context
def wordsafter(keyword, source):
        wordcount=len(source) # shows number of words in sample text
        print(wordcount)
        res_strings=[]    
        for i, val in enumerate(source):
            if val == keyword:
                res_str=(' '.join(source[i:i + 10]))  # shows searchterm and subsequent "n" words
                res_strings.append(res_str)
            
        return(res_strings) # returns list of results
    
# open input txt file from local path
with open('C:\\Users\\input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:  # open file
    data1 = f.read()  # read content of file as string
    data2 = data1.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()  # remove punctuation
    data3 = " ".join(data2.split())  # remove additional whitespace from text
    indata = list(data3.split())  # convert string to list

# define searchterms and call function    
searchterms = ["proclamation", "king"] 
for keyword in searchterms:
    result = wordsafter(keyword, indata)
    if result:
        print(result) 
        with open('C:\\Users\\output.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
            file.write(str(result)) # write output to file
```